# Why all rows are cleared during REPAIR TABLE operation of MySQL?

Tags: windows-7, backup, mysql

I have zpanel installed in my Windows 7 machine for running php and MySQL. Both php and MySQL ran well until today (18-Aug-2016), but today I found one of my MySQL tables is not accessible from php and phpmyadmin and later I found it is crashed. When I went through phpmyadmin, I found it is stated "in use" in MySQL table description under that particular database. Then I tried `REPAIR TABLE (tablename)` from sql query under the database of phpmyadmin. The table is repaired successfully but all of my data (table rows) got deleted or empty (I am not sure, row count is zero). There were thousands of rows of data. But while I am inserting new data to that repaired table, it is using next id (auto increment) of previously crashed table.

My question is:
Is there any way to get back my rows of that crashed table after repair?

[In the auto-generated backup, I found that crashed table has no rows even before a month ago (data backup is kept for each day for two months) although the table crashed today. But all other tables (there are three tables) of the same database have rows intact.]

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MySQL official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html):

> **Caution**
>
> Make a backup of a table before performing a table repair operation;
>   under some circumstances the operation might cause data loss. Possible
>   causes include but are not limited to file system errors. See Chapter
>   8, Backup and Recovery.

You say this table has stopped having data a month ago, so unless this table lays in a different filesystem, I would discard this to be the reason (because your other tables would also possibly be affected). This also says that filesystem errors are not the only one reasons, though.

It seems to me that `REPAIR TABLE` did not do any harm to your table, but some event about 1 month ago did and that's what you stopped having data in that table. Without further information is hard to give tips, but these might include:

- Code changes that involve incorrect `DELETE FROM` statements deleting all rows.
- Maintenance scripts that are not running properly and deleting correct rows.
- [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks allowing a remote attacker to delete that table content.
- ...